# how to pass object in inline onclick event in dynamically creating elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating a table row dynamically. Each row is having `onclick` event. When I click on that table row I want to pass row object to a function but my problem is, while passing that object, I am getting `[object object]` string. So I am not able to use that object in function.

Please give some solution thanks in advance.

This is my code:

```
  var row;
  $.each(mydata, function(i,data){
            row+='<tr onclick="myfunction(\''+data+'\')"><td >data.name</td><td >data.age</td></tr>;
    });
 $("#myTable").append(row);
```

Comment: what is "row" in your code

Comment: sorry now I changed my code .row is a variable and data is a object

Comment: something like this.. `<tr onclick="myfunction("[object Object]'')>....`?

Comment: yeah...  I am getting like this.I am not able to use this.What to do.

Comment: By that way..it wont be possible as everything will be converted finally to string...

Answer (score 1):

I would better use jQuery for defining `click` event handlers. Here is your updated code:

```
var $table = $("#myTable");
$.each(mydata, function(i,row){
        $tr = $('<tr>').appendTo($table);
        $tr.on("click", myfunction);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert the data object to the following style string.

```
"{\"name\": \"lenient\", \"age\": 18}"
```

Then bind it to the click event, you will get the object as the parameter inside the click function.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `JSON.stringify()`

```
onclick="myfunction("+JSON.stringify(data) +")"
```